# a dom node's coordinate

Tags: java, dom, nodes

in my program, i need to get the coordinate of a `org.w3c.dom.Node node` corresponding to a point at the screen as the Dom is a unique data structure of a html file, how is it possible?

```
            Parser p = new Parser();
                SAX2DOM sax2dom = null;
        org.w3c.dom.Node doc  = null;



  URL url = new URL("some adr");
        p.setFeature(Parser.namespacesFeature, false);
        p.setFeature(Parser.namespacePrefixesFeature, false);
        sax2dom = new SAX2DOM();
        p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
        p.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())));
        doc = sax2dom.getDOM();
        html =doc.getFirstChild();
```

EDIT"
i dont want to get the coordinate based on a mouse action,just wondered if when transferring the DOM back into the HTML doc,there will be any chance using codes independent from Input device,to get the position,cause the engine im using.has a function to get the node or coordinate of a point then scroll the browser to point as soon as page loads. so i thought when the engine provides it, then there is a possibility to get Node's position too.here you can see [link](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra-api/org/lobobrowser/html/HtmlRendererContext.html#scrollBy%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: `Node node in the screen` - huh? What do you mean? Please rephrase your question so that we get enough detail to provide an answer.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar how abt now?

Comment: Ok... so: What do you mean `in the screen`? Are you displaying the XML file? What are you doing at all? How should an XML node (which is just text in a text file) be `in a screen` at all? Provide more detail on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar doesnt a dom describe a html page? then a node has a place in the page?then that node has a coordinate in the screen that being shown? isn it clear??

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i bet u even didnt bother to read the code

Comment: No, a DOM *does not* necessarily describe a HTML page. I can parse any XML code into a DOM. While every HTML page can also be represented as a DOM, not every DOM represents a HTML page. Even if it did, the position of the respective element in the HTML page would depend on many different factors (like formatting, window size, etc.), so while you could use JavaScript within a browser to determine the position of an element, you can not "guess" from just reading the XML. And also: No, your question is not clear at all, and yes, I did read the question.

Comment: May I ask what the Parser has to do with coordinates (as long as they are not attributes of a node or something similar)? That's something a renderer would take care of and it has nothing to do with a DOM parser or with the DOM itself. That's what @Thorsten Dittmar was saying as well.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar so if u bother to read my code you will see i parsed a url into a dom tree, now if i got a node of this damn tree , i want to know where it will be if we transfer the damn tree to the html page!

Comment: Now I must assume that you did not read (or fully understand) my comment. Cursing won't help. A webbrowser for example reads a document (HTML) into an internal data structure (DOM) and then renders the elements onto a canvas based on formatting information (e.g. CSS). This is what you see when you open a web page. Only the browser has information about where it placed which element. The browser does *not* only get this information from the document it reads. Simply by reading a document you can't know. So your question comes down to: how do I program my own web browser control.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible with a SAX-parser.

A SAX-parser will parse a XML-document to get the content in its context.

HTML and XML are different things.

- A HTML is a markup description It says something like "This is a heading".
- XML is a structural description of content. It says somsing like "there is a object called PERSON, it has a attribute called NAME"

The HTML content has no postion. The position comes from the rendering engine which will generate a view to this data. The positioning is made by applying CSS.

If you want to get the position of an element inside a HTML document, you'll need a browser-rendering engine. You may try the [selenium testdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/).

[This article may help.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/selenium-how-to-get-x-and-y-coordinate-position)

Comment: That's what I've been trying to make clear for the last 30 minutes or so - let's see whether you are successful in explaining the impossibility of the task :-)

Comment: i know what you mean, but i dont want to get the coordinate based on a mouse action,just wondered if when transferring the DOM back into the HTML doc,there will be any chance using codes independent from Input device,to get the position,cause the engine im using.has a function to get the node or coordinate of a point then scroll the browser to point as soon as page loads. so i thought when the engine provides it, then there is a possibility to get Node's position too.here you can see [link](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra-api/org/lobobrowser/html/HtmlRendererContext.html#scrollBy(int,%20int))

Comment: I think you should mention in your question, that you have a java implemented browser.

Comment: Remember when I said in the beginning that your question was lacking information on what you're trying to achieve? One might be tempted to think that it would have been useful to have this information from the start...